# Parse PFQuery across a relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a custom Parse class...

```
Follow
-----------------
Follower - PFUser
Followee - PFUser
```

I've also added a custom field `fullName` to the User table.

This can't change. (It can be added to though)

I've done several queries using it and I'm stumbling on this last one.

I'd like to be able to run a query that returns Users whose `fullName` contains some given text but only users who are following the current user.

i.e.

If `Paul` and `Peter` are following me there will be Follow objects where I am the followee and they are the follower. Also, `Phillip` is not following me so there is no Follow record for him.

If I run this query with the search text `@"P"` then it should return Peter and Paul and not Phillip.

I just can't work out how to create the query.

I have tried something like this...

```
PFQuery *followQuery = [CCFollow query];
[followQuery whereKey:@"followee" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

PFQuery *nameQuery = [PFUser query];
[nameQuery whereKey:@"fullName" contains:searchText];
[nameQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalsKey:@"follower" inQuery:followQuery];
```

But it returns no error and no objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[nameQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalsKey:@"follower" inQuery:followQuery];
```

This line of code is not correct. Here, the key objectId is of type string and followers is of type PFUser. You could create an extra column "followerString" which stores the objectId of the follower in string format so that you can compare.

Answer (score 1):

The better option is to switch your query around:

Get all `Follow` records where `followee` is the current user and `follower` is contained in a query of `User` records that match your `fullName` query.

```
PFQuery *followQuery = [CCFollow query];
[followQuery whereKey:@"followee" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

PFQuery *nameQuery = [PFUser query];
[nameQuery whereKey:@"fullName" contains:searchText];

// here's the difference:
[followQuery whereKey:@"follower" matchesQuery:nameQuery];
// include follower
[followQuery includeKey:@"follower"];
// now run find on followQuery (not nameQuery)
[followQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *follows, NSError *error) {
    // "follows" now contains the follow records, and the "follower" field
    // has been populated. For example:
    for (PFObject *follow in follows) {
         // This does not require a network access.
         PFObject *follower = follow[@"follower"];
         NSLog(@"retrieved related user: %@", follower);
         // could put them in an array or whatever to bind to the UI
    }
}];
```

Doing it this way you don't need to change you schema or start storing objectId references as a string.

Comment: This is in fact what I'm doing somewhere else. The only problem with this is that I get back an array of Follows. I can include the User in them but pity it can't work the way I'm trying. Thanks. Will have a look at both options.

Comment: If you want the `follower` to be populated, use `includeKey:`... will update my answer to show it.

Comment: That's what I'm doing elsewhere. I may have to fall back to this here too. Not ideal though as it means receiving a load of bloated data and then removing the stuff I don't need.

Comment: The only extra data you get this way is the other fields on `follow` which from what you have shown is just one pointer. Very little bloat unless I am missing something?

Comment: Yes I know. But the Place I'm using this already exists. I'm trying to add additional functionality to a shared control that already deals with Users. Anyway, I have two options now. I'll look at both and use the one I find most convenient/efficient. Thanks.